# How to Index several text in line by line with same keyword?

Tags: c#

I have a problem reading the text file. the problem is that I can't index some of the same text.

this is an example of the text that I want to index

```
add_ace resource.essentialmode command.sets allow
add_ace resource.essentialmode command.add_principal allow
add_ace resource.essentialmode command.add_ace allow

# These resources will start by default.
start mapmanager
start chat
start spawnmanager
start sessionmanager
start fivem
start hardcap
start rconlog
#start scoreboard
#start playernames
start bob74_ipl
```

I try using   `File.ReadAllLines()` method. But I only can read all line or specific line. 
Here the code

```
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines("indextext.txt");
    foreach (string s in readText)
    {  //Read All line
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
    //Read Spesific line
    Console.writeline(readText[1]);
```

What I want is to read lines of text beginning with the word "start". so the result if saved to the string array

```
//first index
start mapmanager

//second index
start chat

etc.
```

but I don't know the code or function to do that. Help me

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, We would like to know what you tried so far? please add code

Comment: Welcome to SO. First, please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to read a file and extract all the lines that start with the keyword 'start ' and store them in a collection. If that is the case:

```
var commands = new List<string>();

using (var sr = new StreamReader("PATH TO FILE"))
{
    var line = sr.ReadLine();

    while (line != null)
    {
        if (line.ToLower().StartsWith("start "))
        {
            commands.Add(line);
        }

        line = sr.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: i try write var command on console but the value is empty/null

Comment: @DroidNetPC I don't understand. Why do you try to write 'var command' in the console? Don't you need the variable in your code? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I just want to get the text beginning with the word "start" and then save it to the string array. then I will separate all the text from the string array to the string

Comment: @DroidNetPC Well, this is your solution then. I didn't understand why you type 'var commands' in the console. Currently, after you execute the code I provided, you'll have all lines that start with 'start ' fetched from the file you provide by changing the "PATH TO FILE" with your file's path in a string array(or list) called commands and you can use it as you like.

Comment: can you add a example?. sorry i am new on c#

Comment: @DroidNetPC Just copy the code from above and change the "PATH TO FILE" with the path to your file. After the code above, you can inspect the 'commands' variable, which is basically "an array" of all the lines in the file that start with the keyword 'start '. I am not sure how can I help you more than that. What exactly you're struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if(line.StartsWith("start"))
                {
                    string[] splitArray = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }).ToArray();
                    Console.WriteLine(splitArray[1]);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it does.  The code inside the method main will work in any application.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you can not conditionally read from something that you don't already know, so you need to at least read a line and then apply the condition to the line that has been read.

I would recommend implementing this in a fashion that helps separate concerns to give you added flexibility.

```
class Program
{
    private static LineSelectionStrategy _lineSelectionStrategy;
    private static string _pathToFile;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _lineSelectionStrategy = new LineSelectionStrategy();
        // You can later define this in the args if using a console app if you want.
        _pathToFile = "Define Path here";
        var relativeCommands = ReadTextFileWithStrategy();

        // If you want to strongly type these, you can then go on to do something like this...
        IEnumerable<TextCommand> commands = relativeCommands.Select(cmdLine => new TextCommand(cmdLine));
        // Do stuff with your 'commands'
    }

    // Clean, simple, light-weight text reader
    static IEnumerable<string> ReadTextFileWithStrategy()
    {
        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(_pathToFile))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (_lineSelectionStrategy.LineMeetsCondition(line))
                    results.Add(line);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

The model and strategy classes ...

```
// Flexible strategy you can tinker with and change without affecting the main program.
public class LineSelectionStrategy
{
    public bool LineMeetsCondition(string line)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            return false;
        return line.StartsWith("start"); // Add your condition here
    }
}

// Represents a command in a text file comprised of an execution function
// and a command / app / action to run with that function.
public class TextCommand
{
    public string Function { get; }
    public string Action { get; }

    private readonly char[] _commandSeparators = { ' '};

    public TextCommand(string textLine)
    {
        var elements = textLine.Split(_commandSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        Function = elements.FirstOrDefault();
        Action = elements.LastOrDefault();
    }
}
```